# Calculate integer input length

Tags: solidity

I need to get the length of input which is an integer in bytes

```
function mine(string s , uint i ) public view returns () {
        return (length of i);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the length of an integer? The decimal string length (for example 123456 has length 6) or the hexadecimal byte length (for exampple 0x1199FF has length 3)? Or something else?

Comment: It is an integer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the amount of bytes needed to represent the number, you can use a loop to count the amount of times you must shift 8 bits to the right to reach 0:

```
uint256 length = 0;
uint256 tempI = i;
while (tempI != 0) { tempI >>= 8; length++; }
```

This will give these results:

`length == 0` when `i == 0x0000000000`

`length == 1` when `i == 0x0000000044`

`length == 2` when `i == 0x0000000555`

`length == 2` when `i == 0x0000006666`

`length == 3` when `i == 0x0000778899`

If you want to count the amount of bits occupied by the number, you can shift by 1 instead of 8: `tempI >>= 1`

Answer (score 2):

In Solidity `uint` is an alias of `uint256`. Its length is fixed. `uint256` is made up of 256 bits, which is 32 bytes. So, a `uint` always has a length of 32 bytes. It does not make sense to calculate the length of it.