# How to check if a mapping has not been written yet?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, mapping

I have this mapping:

```
mapping (uint256 => string ) private storedData;
```

I am trying to do this:

```
modifier dataNotStored(uint256 _index) {
        require( keccak256(abi.encodePacked(storedData[_index])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('')) );
        _;
    }

    function set(uint _index, string calldata _data_to_store) external dataNotStored(_index) {
        storedData[_index] = _data_to_store;
    }
```

My goal is to allow only one write for each entry of the mapping.

I think it is working, because from Remix IDE I get error only when trying a rewrite.

Is there a more efficient and intelligent way to avoid to overwrite a mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the modifier and the hashing. It is simpler to do:

```
function set(uint _index, string calldata _data_to_store) external {
    require(bytes(storedData[_index]).length == 0);
    storedData[_index] = _data_to_store;
}
```

Checking the length of the `bytes` was inspired by [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13864/44893).

Comment: Side question: is more efficient a require or a modifier

Comment: @realtebo: `modifier` is just sugar-syntax. It has no impact on the output byte-code, hence no impact on gas-cost performance.