# (Update Solidity ^0.8.0) How to check string length?

Tags: solidity, string

There is a question about this from [four years ago](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/is-it-possible-to-check-string-variables-length-inside-the-contract). One answer suggests using `bytes(str).length`, which still works as described, as an estimate that potentially overestimates the number of characters.

The exact solution posted there works in what was the latest compiler version back then (`0.4.11`), but it does not work on a current version (`0.8.11`). So this works:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.11;

contract utf8StringLength
{

function utfStringLength(string str) constant
returns (uint length)
{
    uint i=0;
    bytes memory string_rep = bytes(str);

    while (i<string_rep.length)
    {
        if (string_rep[i]>>7==0)
            i+=1;
        else if (string_rep[i]>>5==0x6)
            i+=2;
        else if (string_rep[i]>>4==0xE)
            i+=3;
        else if (string_rep[i]>>3==0x1E)
            i+=4;
        else
            //For safety
            i+=1;

        length++;
    }
}
}
```

But it fails with `pragma solidity 0.8.11;`. Even making some quick fixes, like changing the function header to `function utfStringLength(string memory str) public pure returns (uint length)` throws errors like `TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types bytes1 and int_const 6` for `string_rep[i]>>5==0x6`. `string_rep[i]>>5==bytes1(0x6)` or `string_rep[i]>>5==bytes1(6)` do not work either. Is there a better way to get the exact string length in current compiler versions than using an old compiler version?

Comment: It is not hard to update the code to solc v0.8, see the updated inswer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13886. The only thing missing in your attempt was to make an explicit cast `0x1E` ---> `bytes1(uint8(0x1E))`.

Comment: That works, cheers!